# Dynamic actions support for order object

Tags: administration, dynamic, form, app-builder, custom-actions

I had enable dynamic action and change the visibility in the order object, it works fine on desktop, but not for mobile. I tried to find something but I didn't find nothing related to support for mobile in order object..

If really doesn't have this option for mobile, which alternative could I used?

Comment: You should file a support case

Comment: According to the documentation Dynamic Actions are only supported for Desktop on Standard Objects: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lightning_app_builder_create_dynamic_action.htm&type=5

Comment: @CallumMacErlich - you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this as an answer as suggested, but as of Summer '23 Dynamic Actions are only supported for Desktop of Standard Objects.

Given this restriction doesn't apply on Custom Objects, this may change in the future which is why I'm including the release that this answer is being given in relation to.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.lightning_app_builder_create_dynamic_action.htm&type=5

Comment: that is `summer 23`, not `summer 22` - typo

Comment: Great catch, thanks @cropredy!